# Laravel PHPIDS Include in Every File

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, intrusion-detection

I am using the laravel 4 framework. I recently updated composer.json to include PHPIDS. I read the documentation and understand how to implement it, but is there a quick way to filter ALL of the pages on my site, instead of just one? In short, is there a way that I could implement it where it would be included in every page of the site?

Comment: Yes. [Consider filters](http://culttt.com/2013/09/16/use-laravel-4-filters/) or generic before routing hooks.

Comment: Now I'm having some difficulties with the filter. Could you post some example code?

Comment: I don't have examples, which is why I only commented: my answer is theoretical.  Update your post with your code so far, and we can work on it together.